# javascript Slice is not doing shallow copy

Tags: javascript

I wrote this following JS program to solve the N-queen problem and it works fine.
But then I was trying to modify the output with a particular format.
Then I observed a strange issue.

If you look at the below code, in the function, 'findSolution' I am passing an array - 'board'.
Then I am taking a copy of this array  in this line -

```
let boardCp=board.slice(); //Board is an array of arrays (idea is to never modify the original board object)
```

This copy is then passed to another function for modification.
When that function modifies this copy, the original array ('board' in this case) should remain unchanged - right?
But surprisingly I see that the original array is also being modified.

Can someone please help me understand why is this happening? Please let me know if I need to give further details.

```js
 var solveNQueens=function(A)
 {
  var retArr=[];
  
  var board=[];
  for(var i=0;i<A;i++)
  {
   var row=[];
   for(var j=0;j<A;j++)
   {row.push('.');}
  board.push(row);
  }    
  
  findSolution(board.slice(),A,0,{},retArr); 
  return retArr;
 }

 var findSolution=function(board,boardSize,rowNum,queenpositions,retArr)
 {  
  for(var j=0;j<boardSize;j++)
  {
   if(rowNum==0)
    queenpositions={};

   if(isSafeToPlace(rowNum,j,queenpositions))
    {  
    var foundSolutionsToOtherQueens=true;
    queenpositions[rowNum]=j;   
    var nextRowNum=rowNum+1;
    if(nextRowNum<boardSize)
    foundSolutionsToOtherQueens=findSolution(board,boardSize,nextRowNum,Object.assign({},queenpositions),retArr);
       else
    {
      debugger;
      let boardCp=board.slice();
         retArr.push(convertQueenPositionToArray(boardCp,queenpositions));      
      }
  
    if(!foundSolutionsToOtherQueens)
     delete queenpositions[rowNum];
    
   }
      }   
   return false;
 }
 
 var convertQueenPositionToArray=function(boardCp,queenpositions)
 {
  for(var i=0;i<boardCp.length;i++)
  {   
   var row=boardCp[i];
   for(var j=0;j<row.length;j++)
   {
   if(queenpositions.hasOwnProperty(i) && j==queenpositions[i]) 
    row[j]='Q';
   }
  }
  return boardCp;
 }
 
 var isSafeToPlace=function(rowNum,j,existingQueenpositions)
 {
  for(var prop in existingQueenpositions)
  {
   var colmn=existingQueenpositions[prop];   
   if(colmn===j || colmn==(j-(rowNum-prop)) || colmn==(j+(rowNum-prop)))
    return false;   
  }
  return true;
 }
```

Comment: How is board being modified? Is the original array being modified, or are the objects within the original array being modified? `var x = []; console.log(x === x.slice())` - it's false. slice does copy the array

Comment: How (and where) are you determining that `board` has been altered? @Jaromanda that’s almost definitely a typo in the title, the code uses `slice`

Comment: My apologies, the title is misleading.... I meant to say 'slice' and not 'splice'

Comment: `Board is an array of arrays` - I am assuming you interpret the elements of the contained arrays changing as a change in the array, which is just not how this works... `slice` will copy the references to the elements and the copied array will have copied references to the same contained arrays...

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So are you saying if I slice each contained array then it should solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slice` method DOES NOT make deep copy.

It only copies the first layer of the array (sting and number only).

Let's consider the example below:

```js
const nestedArray = [
  1,
  [2, 3],
  { y1: 4, y2: 5},
];

const cloneArray = nestedArray.slice();

// this is safe
cloneArray[0] = 'new value 1';
console.log(nestedArray[0]); // expect 1

// cloneArray[1] is a pointer to the original array
cloneArray[1][0] = 'new value 2';
console.log(nestedArray[1]); // expect 2, got 'new value 2'

// cloneArray[2] s a pointer to the original object
cloneArray[2].y1 = 'new value 4';
console.log(nestedArray[2]); // expect { y1: 4, y2: 5}, got { y1: 'new value 4', y2: 5}
```

- If you need a deep copy for nested array or object, you have to do it recursively or use a third part library, such as **lodash**: `var cloneArray = _.cloneDeep(nestedArray)`
- Another shortcut solution is to do `JSON.parse(JSON.stingify(nestedArray))`

Comment: If its shallow copy, why is the first example safe? (cloneArray[0] = 'new value 1') Shouldn't this also change the nestedArray?